# Apending two columns of data in One column is Sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns A & B i need to append them in a sequential order and obtains the result such as Column A first cell followed by column B first cell followed by Column A second cell followed by column B second cell

**Column A**
Jones
android
1234FG
thepark

**Column B**
JONES
ANDROID
1234SS
PARK

**Result**
Jones
JONES
android
ANDROID
1234FG
1234SS
thepark
PARK

Kindly advise any formulas or VBA code to obtain the given result.

Comment: Hi Srinath, welcome to SO. People here are not here to write your code for free. `vba` string operator to concatenate is `&`.

Comment: Do you need the result to be in one cell or in the cells of the corresponding rows (i.e. Jones JONES in C1, android ANDROID in C2, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

please see the below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim output As String
    Dim text1 As String
    Dim text2 As String
    Dim text1split1
    Dim text1split2
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        text1 = Range("A" & i).Value
        text2 = Range("B" & i).Value
        text1split1 = Split(text1, " ")
        text1split2 = Split(text2, " ")
        For j = 0 To UBound(text1split1)
            If output <> "" Then
                output = output & " " & text1split1(j) & " " & text1split2(j)
            Else
                output = text1split1(j) & " " & text1split2(j)
            End If
        Next j
        Range("C" & i).Value = output
    Next i
End Sub
```